# PHP Codeigniter- Allow users to use a custom domain name

Tags: php, codeigniter, dns, domain-mapping

I am currently working on a codeigniter project.

I have a Codeigniter v3.0.0 web site, at example.com.

Now here I want my website users to use their custom domain name. Let's say a user signs up on my website, then he will get his own page: user1.example.com. Also he will be given an option to add his custom domain name. Let's say user adds his custom domain name as abc.com

Now I would like to point this custom user domain abc.com to user1.example.com.
This needs to be dynamic as there can be any number of users.

I do not want a redirect, but the URL should remain at abc.com.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you think for abc.example.com ?

Comment: I mean abc.com should point to user1.example.com

Comment: Not possible. You can use subdomain like  abc.example.com. otherwise you need to register each user domain.

Comment: Its really a big thing what you ask. Once I done with creating subdomain in cpanel using codeigniter. but creating of custom domain name like abc.com; I never did it.

Comment: we are not creating abc.com.... we are just domain mapping here..i am sure there must be some way

Comment: well it's not possible but you able to don't change your base url and give user access url like `xyz.com/user_name_or_custom_name_select_by_user`

Answer (score 0):

Open your hosts file (/etc/hosts) 
add following
127.0.0.1        test.domain.com
(localhost IP)   (your custom domain)
save it. 
Go to browser and search "test.domain.com"
It will work.